# is it possible to add functionality to all controller actions in ASP.NET Core without calling a method in all of them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

Is it possible to add functionality to all controller actions in ASP.NET Core?

For example, ASP.NET Core uses the `[Authorize]` attribute to validate users from the bearer header. Is it possible to get identity and claims without writing a separate logic in controller actions? Because it causes calling the same method in every action.

Assume I have this code:

```
private UserModel GetCurrentUser()
{
    var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    if (identity != null)
    {
        var userClaims = identity.Claims;

        return new UserModel
                   {
                       Username = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value,
                       EmailAddress = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value,
                       GivenName = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value,
                       Surname = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type  == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value,
                       Role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value
                   };
    }

    return null;
}
```

I need to call `GetCurrentUser()` in every action method to get the user id and other identities.

ASP.NET Core has `[FromService]` attribute; maybe I can write a service for it to get the result of the method directly from action parameters but don't know how to use it.

Comment: The `ControllerBase` class already has the `User` property which is the `ClaimsPrincipal`. You could write your own `MyCustomControllerBase : ControllerBase` class and handle the conversion of the claims from the `ClaimsPrincipal` to the `UserModel` there, on that class -> then any controller class inheriting from `MyCustomControllerBase` has this `UserModel` available - without having to write any more code in every controller / action method ....

Comment: @marc_s thank you for writing the comment. can you write the answer with a code sample? i will accept it.

Comment: @marc_s and please assume that  authorization is not the only scenario. for example we have microservices that only one service can authorize users and other services can make a call to that service through rest or grpc etc.. to get user info.

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? If you need any further assistance feel free to share your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own controller base class, to handle this conversion of the `ClaimsPrincipal` to the `UserModel`, and then let your own controllers inherit from that custom base class which exposes this `UserModel` as a property.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    public UserModel CurrentUserModel { get; private set; }  
    
    public CustomControllerBase : base()
    {
        CurrentUserModel = GetCurrentUser();
    }
    
    private UserModel GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var userClaims = User.Claims;

        return new UserModel
                   {
                       Username = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value,
                       EmailAddress = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value,
                       GivenName = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value,
                       Surname = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type  == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value,
                       Role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value
                   };
    }
}
```

Then derive your own controllers from this custom base class, and access your user model class in any method you need:

```
public class HomeController : CustomControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // You have access to "CurrentUserModel" here
        string fullName = $"{CurrentUserModel.GivenName} {CurrentUserModel.Surname}";
        
        // do whatever you need to do here
        return View();
    }
}
```

This approach works for *anything* - not just related to authentication. Whatever you want to have available / exposed on *any* of your controllers - put it in your custom controller base class.